# Titanium, creating action listener for any button pressed on screen

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, titanium

So i have 9 buttons on a screen, i want an action listener such that:

```
-sudo code-

    frame3.buttion.event-handle({ this.title='clicked'})

-sudo code-
```

the way i have it now is having 9 different buttons and event-handlers lol, not cool. also is there a way to make an array of buttons and added and manipulate them from that array, like array[0].title=clicked?

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
var buttons = new Array();
buttons[i] = Ti.UI.createButton({
    ..........
    //Add this
    my_id:i
});
```

This can be fetched again later

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function(e)){ 
    var i = e.source.my_id;
    myAction[i] = Ti.Media.createSound({ url: sounds[i] }).play();
    Ti.API.info("clicked button: " + i+ " : "+ myAction[i]);
});
```

or

```
buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function(e)){ 
    var i = e.source.my_id;
    doSomething(i); //function that handles click.
});
```

Comment: how do i add it to screen. frame3.add(buttons[i]) gives error?

Comment: var frame3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
 backgroundColor: 'black'
})

Comment: and how do you go about adding them? using a for loop?

Comment: have a look [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/84241/dynamically-assign-listener-to-button) did you add var buttons = new Array(); first? I forgot that...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a completely different approach.

```
1) create a view and place all of the buttons in the view.
2) associated one eventListener to the view containing the buttons
3) when the view gets a click event, it will bubble up to the buttons; check the
  event.source.id to determine which button was clicked.
```